# Pronunciation of the word Leicester

Tags: pronunciation

I was playing Monopoly the other day (haven't played for some time) and I bought Leicester Square. However, everytime someone landed on my block, I was unsure as to its pronunciation. So far I've heard two:

> **Lei-*ses*-ter Square**
>   and
>   **Lei-*ches*-ter Square**

Which is the correct pronunciation?

Comment: Is this a British version of Monopoly? The American one doesn't have any place named *Leicester Square*.

Comment: Original, apparently.

Comment: And the hardest block to pronounce on the American one is *Reading Railroad*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

lĕs′·tər

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_names_in_English_with_counterintuitive_pronunciations#L

Comment: Totally amazing! Since you live in England, have you ever been to Leicester Square?

Comment: Yes. What's more, I live in a town called Flitwick. Pronounced Flit·ick

Comment: Oh, yes, I understand the pronounciation for that. You see, in Australia, I live near a suburb called Berwick, pronounced Ber-ick

Comment: @Third Australian pronunciations of English names can be so terrible sometimes. E.g. the footballer Chris Mainwaring which they pronounce main-wearing :/

Comment: Americans asking for directions to "Lei-ses-ter/Lei-ches-ter Square" are a bit of a London tourist stereotype. Especially if they're at Covent Garden and are trying to get there on the Tube.

Comment: And let's not forget my personal favourite, Towcester, pronounced "Toaster".

Comment: (To provide context to [e100](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3404/e100)'s comment about the tube, Leicester Square and Covent Garden stations are 100 yards  apart; it's quicker to travel between them above ground.)

Answer (score -1):

As I am from the City Leicester I would pronounce it as "LEST-TER"

Comment: Would you really pronounce T twice?